# Django sign-up form scroll default

Tags: django

Hi in Django I have created a sign-up page, but the problem is if the page is loaded the page automatically scrolls to the e-mail field of the form instead of the top of the page.

How can I stop this?

Comment: what signup page did you use? django-allauth?

Comment: created  a class based create view

Comment: Then can you upload your temlpate and form?